# Oracle interfaces - Postgresql

Tags: oracle, interface, postgresql-9.5, dblink

I need to create interfaces between two different databases. I have an Oracle database and another Postgresql database.

The problem is that the schemas and structures of the databases are different.
I have performed migration / interface processes between two Postgresql databases before, but never with Oracle.

I think it is possible to do it with DBlink.
I need to keep both databases updated (bidirectional).
What do you suggest is a good alternative?

Comment: You say "bidirectional": does this mean both databases are updating the same entities? (Normally I would say tables, but your remark that the schemas and structures are different suggests that tables might not be common.) Also, which version (and Edition) of Oracle? I don't suppose you have GoldenGate licensed?

Comment: @APC The entities (tables) are different, differ in their structure and type of data.
The idea is to maintain a "bidirectional" update between the two.
The Oracle 11.2 version and the Postgresql version is 11.
With two postgresql bases I could do it, creating dblink and assembling views (VW) at the origin with the expected structure at the destination, then I executed it from the other side by means of a stored procedure.
The idea is to be able to do something similar with oracle and postgresql, if possible, but I understand that I will have to use services.